# Running Docker maven container

Tags: java, docker, maven

I want to copy maven project from my dekstop to [maven container](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven) and compile it in container

I run the command :

```
docker run -it --rm --name my-maven-project -v "/Users/ahay/Desktop/aviv" -w "/usr/share" maven:3.6.3-jdk-8 mvn clean install
```

And get the error :

[image]

But from -v flag diractory I have pom.xml :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The issue probably just comes from the fact the working directory (CLI option `-w`) you set did not match the path of your project (CLI option `-v`).

So I guess you could try the following:

```
docker run -it --rm --name my-maven-project \
  -v "/Users/ahay/Desktop/aviv:/usr/src/app" \
  -w "/usr/src/app" maven:3.6.3-jdk-8 mvn clean install
```

or equivalently:

```
cd /Users/ahay/Desktop/aviv
docker run -it --rm --name my-maven-project \
  -v "$PWD:/usr/src/app" \
  -w "/usr/src/app" maven:3.6.3-jdk-8 mvn clean install
```